# vuetify transition of v-flex

Tags: vue.js, transition, vuetify.js

I'm trying to implement transition like here [codepen example](https://codepen.io/udyux/pen/EwwPgr) but using the Vuetify.

I've noticed that adding transition tag before v-flex component destroyed a v-flex order. In this example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/w2l1wkr5n8), there are two routes one with transition another one without.

Components have the structure:

```
<v-container>
  <v-layout row wrap pb-2 pt-2>
  <!-- is transition group -->
  <transition-group name="cards" >
    <v-flex xs3
        v-for="card in items"
        :key="card"
        >
        <v-layout>
          <v-card>
            .....
          </v-card>  
        </v-layout>
      </v-flex>
    </transition-group>
  </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

Answer (score 7):

`transition-group` renders an actual element: a `<span>` by default. So there's an extra `span` between `v-layout` and `v-flex`. This cause the flexbox to malfunction.

`transition-group` has to render something. You could set it to render `v-layout` instead of `span`.

**BUT**, `transition-group` has a limitation. It can set `tag` but cannot set `props`. So, for the `row wrap pb-2 pt-2`, you gotta add it manually using CSS.

change

```
<template>
    ...
    <v-layout row wrap pb-2 pt-2>
        <transition-group name="cards">
            ...
        </transition-group>
    </v-layout>
    ...
</template>
```

to

```
<template>
    ...
    <transition-group name="cards" tag="v-layout" class="manual-v-layout">
        ...
    </transition-group>
    ...
</template>


<style>
.manual-v-layout {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-bottom: 8px !important;
  padding-top: 8px !important;
}
</style>
```

and it would work.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/z2z5yoopol

Comment: Thank you, that works! Will never solve it by myself

Comment: Didn't work for me, but i provided a solution that did. However, this answer pointed me in the right direction. Thank you Jacob

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't get Jacob Goh's answer to work, so i made some adjustments with his answer as inspiration and came up with this as the solution.

```
<template>
...
  <transition-group name="cards" tag="div" class="layout row wrap">
    ...
  </transition-group>
...
</template>
```

Set the transition-group tag to div and assign the appropriate classes to it.

Comment: Yes, this solution works and is simplier. You can keep the span tag. Thanks to Jacob Goh for his explanation.